# Mysql return result even id is wrong

Tags: mysql

I am facing an issue when adding a random string after the id value still query return result.

Ideally, it should return an empty result.

```
mysql> select * from pricelists where id = '1abcd';
+----+---------+--------+--------------+--------------+---------------------+-----+-------------------+--------+-------------+--------------------+----------------+------------+---------------------+---------------------+---------------+
| id | name    | markup | routing_type | quality_base | initially_increment | inc | shadow_billing_id | status | reseller_id | pricelist_id_admin | routing_prefix | call_count | creation_date       | last_modified_date  | decimal_value |
+----+---------+--------+--------------+--------------+---------------------+-----+-------------------+--------+-------------+--------------------+----------------+------------+---------------------+---------------------+---------------+
|  1 | default | 0      |            0 |            1 |                   0 |  60 |                 0 |      0 |           0 |                  0 |                |          0 | 2016-07-25 00:00:00 | 2022-07-06 10:36:31 |             4 |
+----+---------+--------+--------------+--------------+---------------------+-----+-------------------+--------+-------------+--------------------+----------------+------------+---------------------+---------------------+---------------+
1 row in set, 1 warning (0.00 sec)
```

Comment: MySQL is silently trying to convert `'1abcd'` to a int... and it does it wrongly. It converts that value to `1`. You should validate it's an int before using it in the query.

Comment: @TheImpaler, thanks for reply.
So there are no any dynamic solution right?, because I face issue in all int tinyint type field in all table

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> when adding a random string after the id value still query return result. Ideally, it should return an empty result.

This means that `id` column is numeric one, and the comparing have numeric context. The string literal is converted to the numeric value implicitly, and `id` value is compared with numeric `1` value.

You must set string context for the compare. For example, you may use explicit CAST (`where CAST(id AS CHAR) = '1abcd'`) or any implicit convertion (for example, `where CONCAT(id, '') = '1abcd'`).

Answer (score 0):

Its actually no question, but the reason is that this id column is an int column and the value in your condition is automatically parsed to int. So its "1" in the end.