# mysql where working incorrectly for auto increment column

Tags: mysql, mysql-8.0

I have one mysql table with primary key and auto increment value.
It have db-engine is `innodb`. It have charset is `utf8mb3`. mysql version is `8.0.25`.

```
select id,first_name from user where id = '1abcd';
+----+---------------+
| id | first_name    |
+----+---------------+
|  1 | Administrator |
+----+---------------+
```

mysql> select id,first_name from user;

```
+----+------------------------------------------+
| id | first_name                               |
+----+------------------------------------------+
|  1 | Administrator                            |
|  2 | default                                  |
|  3 | default                                  |
|  4 | mayur                                    |
|  5 | singlerandom_cid                         |
|  6 | Dialer with Random CID and single caller |
|  7 | Dialer with Random CID and dynamic calle |
|  8 | Grishma                                  |
|  9 | dialerwithrandomcid                      |
| 10 | Ankit                                    |
| 11 | without campaign                         |
+----+------------------------------------------+
```

Here, If you check id have value is `1` not  `1abcd`. Still it returns value.
Which is not correct.

Any help or suggestions ?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Possible duplicate https://stackoverflow.com/q/72882651/4781696
;)

Comment: *Any help or suggestions ?* Forbid non-numeric literal value usage simply.

Comment: @HP371 indeed it is a duplicate, but why don't you accept an answer ? It seems to me that Akina answer solve your problem

Answer (score 2):

This should work:

```
select id,
       first_name 
from user 
where concat(id * 1) = '1abcd';
```

https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=294ed941005928cfcca345cc8ad9a1f5

The string  is converted to the numeric value  and  the value of id is compared with numeric 1 value.The same would be for '2abcd' or '11abcd', not for 'ab2cd'. Check the fiddle in the link above for more details